# Elasticsearch NEST Buckets Inside Buckets Aggregation

Tags: nest, elasticsearch.net

How can I retrieve the values from a `bucket` inside another `bucket` using `NEST`

[Link to example](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_buckets_inside_buckets.html)

This is how I would normally get bucket values

```
var colors = response.Aggregations.Terms("colors");
```

but how can i get the value of `make`

```
var makes = response.Aggregations.Terms("colors.make");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this seems to work for me, I am not 100% sure if its the correct way of retrieving it.

```
   var nestedBucket = response.Aggregations.Terms("colors").Buckets
                    .Select(_ => _.Terms("make").Buckets);
```